# Trouble with self keyword in python

Tags: python

am creating a browser in ubuntu.. using Glade
when i compile it's showing "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"
code :

```
self.reload = self.bulider.get_object("reload")
def on_pressbutton_clicked(self, widget): print"reload"
```

it is just a sample code to check button's action..

Comment: Think of `self` as `this` if you're coming from Java otherwise you can think of it as "this object that i'm using".

Comment: You're going to need to provide a large code fragment...from what you've got there, the error you see is totally expected.  `self` typically is used in a class method, but your first line doesn't seem to be within a class or method.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you provided, this might be illustrative.  To access a class attribute within a method you use self.  Outside the method you can simply define variables by their name.

```
class test:
  var = "I'm var"
  def printvar(self):
    print(self.var)

>>>a = test()
>>>a.printvar()
I'm var
```